# Parsing XML at RunTime based on XSD with JAXB 2.x

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-parsing

Have a requirement so want to check its feasibility.We are using JAXB 2.x for unmarshling XML in to out existing POJO classes.below is the process we are following..

1. Based on the XSD provided we have already created required classes using JAXB utility.
2. On Run time we are passing only XML file and we first validating the XML with the preexisting XSD and if success than will move ahead with the Unmarshling.
3. For XML creation same process but in reverse order.

Now there is one requirement so the client want that they can pass XML and XSD to the method being developed and this method should hand over the common object as return by parsing that XML and later on they will handle the process of mapping that generic Object with the specific classes.

My question is,Is it possible in Jaxb 2.x that based on the XSD supplied it will first create required classes on the fly and than will parse XML and hand over the result to the client module so they can do the mapping work or is there any way to achieve that functionality??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) (I'm the tech lead) we have a feature called Dynamic JAXB, that lets you bootstrap from an XML schema and use generic objects.  You might find this approach useful:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic
- [Dynamic java bean from xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967480/dynamic-java-bean-from-xsd/3969608#3969608)

Answer (score 0):

I know it Is doable. One student in my lab did almost the same thing on a different subject. Though, you will have to play with classloader to be able to load dynamically the classes you've jest created. Once that is done, you can parse the XML using the classloader that includes the new classes.

Of course, it is not as easy as it sounds like...

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html this is a good start point. The thing is that I didn't do it myself...

Comment: The other problem is that in order to get the parsed object from JAXB, you will nee to use the Object class since you don't know the XSD upfront. this means that you basically can't do a single thing other than reflection to manage the data.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sample samples/inline-customize 
located at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/samples.html