# dynamic java bean from XSD using java

Tags: java, xsd, code-generation

How to create dynamic java bean from XSD using java.
Kindly provide some samples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic java bean from xsd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967480/dynamic-java-bean-from-xsd)

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic java bean"? That doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Dynamic java bean mean any XSD it will support and generate the bean classes

Comment: @user569587: You're just re-arranging the same words. You're not being clear as to what it is you *want*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using JAX-B, the built-in XML-to-object binding API.  No examples now; I have to go to work.

I'd recommend using IntelliJ; it can generate Java Beans from an XSD using JAX-B at the touch of a menu item.  I did it last week - works great, easy to do.

Comment: when you have a time,Please provide one sample.

Comment: You will be smarter if you start digging into JAX-B yourself.  I'm not likely to provide any examples.  I'm volunteering my time, after all.

Comment: can u please provide any reference site or files for this kind of approach then it will very helpful for my development?

Comment: I'd Google for JAX-B docs and tutorials.  Do you need me to do that for you?

Comment: Check out my blog for JAXB examples (I lead EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)):  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/

Comment: Blaise is the lead for the JAXB project, so he's a good source.  His blog is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <schemaFiles>[NameofYour.xsd]</schemaFiles>
                <packageName>[package for generated code]</packageName>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can use something similar to above in your pom if you are using JAXB + Maven.

http://jaxb.java.net/

using command

```
xjc -p primer.po -d src po.xsd
```

The primer.po is the package name  and the src is the generated codes outputing directory name.

http://www.xyzws.com/scdjws/studyguide/jaxb_samples2.0.html

Comment: i want to do this process using java . not ant or maven. so can you provide any details regarding that one then it will helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

u can use XStream to do it.
[two minutes toturial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)

have fun!

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html