# Parse XSD and get a sample XML representantion

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing, xsd, schema

i'm working with parse a WADL and write a XML of this WADL (with my specifications),
when a response have a representation of a element like 'tns:type',
i need to parse the included file XSD and get a sample representation  and insert into the XML i'm creating.
Example:

**XSD FILE INCLUDED IN A WADL EXAMPLE**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:yahoo:yn" xmlns="urn:yahoo:yn" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="ResultSet">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Result" type="ResultType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="50"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="totalResultsAvailable" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="totalResultsReturned" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="firstResultPosition" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="ResultType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Summary" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Url" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="ClickUrl" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="NewsSource" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="NewsSourceUrl" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Language" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="PublishDate" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="ModificationDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Thumbnail" type="ImageType" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ImageType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Url" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Height" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Width" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**And i need this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResultSet totalResultsAvailable="1234" totalResultsReturned="1234" firstResultPosition="1234">
  <Result type="ResultSet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="50">
    <Title type="xs:string"/>
    <Summary type="xs:string"/>
    <Url type="xs:string"/>
    <ClickUrl type="xs:string"/>
    <NewsSource type="xs:string"/>
    <NewsSourceUrl type="xs:string"/>
    <Language type="xs:string"/>
    <PublishDate type="xs:string"/>
    <ModificationDate type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <Thumbnail type="ImageType" minOccurs="0">
      <Url type="xs:string"/>
      <Height type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
      <Width type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
    </Thumbnail>
  </Result>
</ResultSet>
```

I need an API to do this
or if not exists, how would i do?

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967480/dynamic-java-bean-from-xsd/3969608#3969608

Comment: I'm working with this since lunch, but sorry, i can't understand how this supposed to help me ? sorry if it's simple

Comment: the example shows how from a XSD schema. you can generate beans on the fly.  Then you cab use some logic to set random values. Finally, you can output the results an XML.

Comment: but i dont know the output, how i gonna supposed to do a unmarshaller from a XML which i don't know the XSD ? Thanks again !